# Empty list in GrapQL schema- should be null or []?

Tags: graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I have `Post` type with `tags` field that is array of strings, but some posts do not have tags. Is there any convention how to handle 0 items (tags in my example) - from backend should I return `null` in query or empty array `[]`? If this is developer preference and there is no standard for that, what is used more often in all graphql projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to use an empty list (`[]`): https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/issues/1980#issuecomment-970189037