# nestjs/graphql: How to return mixed array of values and nulls?

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, nestjs-graphql

I'm using `@nestjs/graphql` to build graphql API. I have the following object

```js
@ObjectType('Round')
export class RoundDto {
  @Field(() => GraphQLInt)
  round: number;

  @Field(() => [[GraphQLString]])
  teams: Nullable<[string, string]>[];
}
```

How Can I declare the `teams` field to return mixed values of string and null?
Do I need to write own scalar for it?

I'm expecting to receive teams like

```js
teams: [[1, 2], null, [3, 4], null]
```

But getting the error
`Cannot return null for non-nullable field Round.teams.`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this [Answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71622753/empty-list-in-grapql-schema-should-be-null-or), the decision is returning a tuple or empty array

```
@ObjectType('Round')
export class RoundDto {
  @Field(() => GraphQLInt)
  round: number;

  @Field(() => [[GraphQLString]])
  teams: ([string, string] | [])[];
}
```

The answer will be `teams: [[1, 2],[], [3, 4],[]]`